# How can a terminal emulator know what processes are attached?

Tags: macos, terminal-emulator

The OS X Terminal.app has an option to show the "active process name". It displays the name of (one of) the foreground processes within the terminal, with a reasonable degree of accuracy. For example, when running `make`, it shows the names of the various subprocesses involved  in the build process (`cc`, `collect`, `ld`, etc.). How exactly does this work?

My leading hypothesis so far is that it tracks the foreground process group in the attached session, and picks the most-recently-started process within that process group. But, I'm not clear on what system calls or services it uses to implement this.